# Find duplicates in MySql when having a table with updated data

Tags: mysql, sql

I know my question has been answered on many different occasions, but I can't get this to work..

I am trying to get all item ID's that have a duplicate identifier while taking into consideration if the item has been updated or not.

Let's suppose this is the main table that holds the item data

```
========================== item_table =========================
+----------+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+
| store_id | store_item_id | item_id | identifier | update_id |
+----------+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+
|1         | 1:1           | 1       | abc1       | 1         |
|1         | 1:2           | 2       | abc2       | NULL      |
|1         | 1:3           | 3       | abc3       | NULL      |
|1         | 1:4           | 4       | abc1       | 2         |
|1         | 1:5           | 5       | abc1       | NULL      |
|1         | 1:6           | 6       | NULL       | 3         |
|1         | 1:7           | 7       |            | NULL      |
|1         | 1:8           | 8       | abc1       | NULL      |
|2         | 2:9           | 9       | abc1       | NULL      |
+----------+---------------+---------+------------+-----------+
```

And an update table for the items that have been updated (where `id` matches `update_id` from `item_table`)

**The update table overwrites item data and it will be used instead of original item data if defined**

```
===== update_table =====
+---------+------------+
| id      | identifier |
+---------+------------+
| 1       | abc0       |
| 2       | abc4       |
| 3       | abc1       |
+---------+------------+
```

#### **Constraints**

- Only check if `identifier` is not NULL or empty string ''
- Only check against a specific `store_id`
- Only select `item_id`'s where the same `identifier` appears more than twice (i.e. `i.store_item_id <> g.store_item_id` to check if is same item)

I have this following query which checks the original item data with the above constraints, but I can't get it to check for the updated value as well

```
SELECT 
  g.item_id
FROM 
  item_table g
WHERE g.store_id = 1 AND EXISTS (
  SELECT 
    i.identifier 
  FROM 
    item_table i 
  WHERE 
    i.identifier = g.identifier AND 
    i.identifier <> '' AND 
    i.identifier IS NOT NULL AND
    i.store_item_id <> g.store_item_id AND
    i.store_id = 1
)
```

#### **Result:**

```
+---------+
| item_id |
+---------+
| 1       |
| 4       |
| 5       |
| 8       |
+---------+
```

But I need to check the update table as that will be the final data if defined and what my query should return is

#### **Expected Result:**

I need all `item_id`'s where `store_id` is 1 and having the exact same identifier (i.e. `abc1`) checking the `update_table` as well

```
+---------+
| item_id |
+---------+
| 5       |
| 6       |
| 8       |
+---------+
```

I have tried all sorts to get it working such as `JOINS`, `IFNULL`, other ways of using `EXISTS` or using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING`, but mainly I can't get it working because the `update_id` is not always defined. Any ideas?

#### **Edits / Clarification**

- `duplicates` in my case means that the identifier has to be unique for every item. That doesn't mean that it can't be inserted in the DB, I'm just collecting the issues and showing them to the user so they can update and fix the data
- An item can be updated as many times as the user wants, but the new value will be overwritten in the update table instead of creating a new entry

Comment: Lots of table and code, but you dont explain what result you want or what logic follow to get that result.

Comment: You probably need a `LEFT JOIN` with `COALESCE`

Comment: Still not logic, what you mean duplicated?

Comment: How you check if an item is updated ??

Comment: `identifier has to be unique for every product` what is a product? dont see anything on your table .

Comment: why `9` doesnt appear? is also `abc1`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza `9` doesn't appear because it belongs to another store, if you look at the sql, it's checking against store ID 1. Also, product was a typo for item.

Comment: can one item be updated multiple times? what about multiples items with `null` identifier are those consider duplicated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/EOYJ82369)**

```
SELECT item_id
FROM (
        SELECT store_id, item_id, COALESCE(u.`identifier`, i.`identifier`) as `identifier`
        FROM item_table i
        LEFT JOIN update_table u
           ON i.`update_id` = u.`id`
     ) as updated     
JOIN (
        SELECT store_id, COALESCE(u.`identifier`, i.`identifier`) as `identifier`, COUNT(*)
        FROM item_table i
        LEFT JOIN update_table u
           ON i.`update_id` = u.`id` 
        GROUP BY store_id, COALESCE(u.`identifier`, i.`identifier`) 
        HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
     ) as duplicated
  ON updated.`store_id` = duplicated.`store_id`
 AND updated.`identifier` = duplicated.`identifier`

WHERE updated.`identifier` <> ''
  AND updated.`identifier` IS NOT NULL

ORDER BY  item_id;
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: do you have any feedback?

Comment: It does the job, thanks -- just a bit slow for large data sets

Comment: well the problem is your current design cant use proper index :(. Right now you have to calculate the update everytime. Instead of keep the values in a different tables, you should update the current value in your main table and keep the historic changes in a different table

Comment: I agree that would've been better, but the main table updates itself daily with fresh data and everything is being overwritten. So having the updated values in a different table seemed to be the only way to go at the time. Think of it like this, the item `identifier` might change daily from `abc1` to `asd1` or `123455abc` and so on, it can have any value. Now, if the identifier is being updated by the user and set to `xyz1`, the final identifier would be this one, and it would ignore the `identifier` in the main table which might change daily.

Comment: Is up to you, but if this procedure performance is very critical I would give a second look to that design. Otherwise if is just one ocasional check should be ok.